# airflow schedule DAG with unusual times

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to figure out the best way to schedule a DAG in airflow that doesn't conform to the ways that they are typically scheduled.

The times I want the DAG to run are between 9:40 AM and 4:00 PM, Monday-Friday and to run every ten minutes.

1) `cron` could sort of work here as I could set up multiple DAGs that execute the same code and give them different `cron` triggers. For instance, trigger the first to run at 9:40 and run once, run the second at 9:50 (also run once) and then the third run from 10 AM to 4, Mon-Fri every ten minutes.

2) The airflow preset (eg `@hourly`) or timer interval also wouldn't really work here either, since as far as I can tell there is no way to set up a timer interval with the weird start time (9:40 AM) and the Mon-Fri restriction. But at least here I can set the timedelta to 10 minutes.

3) The other option would be to set the scheduler to `None` and have a second script externally trigger the DAG, using the `subprocessing` module.

In my ideal scenario, I could write a generator which would give python `datetimes` that I want the dag to be triggered and give that to the DAG object. I guess I could combine that solution with 3 above.

Solution 1 could work, but seems hacky.

Wanted to know what other folks have done in this situation.

Comment: looks like there is a way to [combine `croniter` objects](https://github.com/kiorky/croniter/pull/23), which is what the [DAG uses for scheduling](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/3ad4f96bae78f16a2240567f65831ca269672d7b/airflow/models/dag.py#L386)....

Comment: doesn't look like you can directly supply a `croniter` object when creating the dag

Comment: How about wrapping your time logic inside a `PythonOperator`? Then use that as a gate in your dag

Comment: Agree with **@LuckyGuess**; the only way I can think of (and a very bad one too) is to begin your DAG with a custom operator (probably extended from `ShortCircuitOperator`) that carries your time logic. With that, you'll have to keep your DAG scheduled every 10 min; but the actual tasks would run only at desired interval (and they'll be skipped remaining times)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. both came across my mind but didn't seem like a good idea. also seems like while both approaches would work, it would forgo some of the benefits of airflow, like having the code only execute when needed and not in a state of constantly "running" but waiting for a datetime to trigger the code to execute

Answer (score 2):

`*/10 9-16 1-5 * *`

This CRON will give you a run every 10 minutes between 9am and 4pm ( 16 hours ) and only Mondays to Fridays ( 0-5 ).

I don't know how you can get the finer granularity to have 9:40am to 4pm.

`*/10` indicates a run every 10 minutes
`9-16` indicates runs only between hour 9 and hour 16
`1-5` indicates runs as per the following table:

```
0 - Sun      Sunday
1 - Mon      Monday
2 - Tue      Tuesday
3 - Wed      Wednesday
4 - Thu      Thursday
5 - Fri      Friday
6 - Sat      Saturday
7 - Sun      Sunday
```